# How to transfer an NSObject pointer to selector in Object C?

Tags: xcode, pointers, selector

I want to transfer an Object pointer as a parameter to me selector, however, it will not allow me to do that, is there anyway to do that?  or is there any workaround here?

I have two Classes, A Class will do something  and then the result feed back to B class.

what I am doing now in A instance:

```
    MyObject *b;
    [b addTarget:self withSelector:@selector(dosomething:) ];
    -(void)dosomething:(NSString **)string
    {
        *string="some thing is implemented";
    }
    B instance:
    {
    NSString *mystring;
        [a performSelector:dosomething withObject:&mystring];
    }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only pass a valid Objective-C object to `-performSelector:withObject:`.

You have three options.

Pass a mutable string:

```
- (void)doSomething:(NSMutableString*)foo
{
    [foo setString:@"Hello"];
}
```

Return a string:

```
- (NSString*)doSomething
{
    return @"Hello";
}
```

Pass an NSValue that contains a NSString**:

```
- (void)doSomething:(NSValue*)value
{
    NSString** stringPointer = (NSString**)[value pointerValue];
    *stringPointer = @"Hello";
}
```